# Calculate switching frequency of an IGBT

Tags: igbt

This might be an elementary question - how can I determine the switching frequency of an IGBT e.g. [IXGH15N120B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/ixys_98659-1547260.pdf)? Will this IGBT be suitable for a switching frequency up to 250 kHz?

Comment: Admittedly I don't know enough about IGBT performance to answer based on the [datasheet numbers](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/ixys_98659-1547260.pdf), but it's worth noting that this part is "Not recommended for new designs" according to the manufacturer (see https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/IXYS/IXGH15N120B?qs=t7yjd2JO%2FgSCIF8pFiRPrA%3D%3D). I still think it's a useful question, insofar as an answer can show a technique applicable to IGBTs in general.

Comment: You're (completely?) ignoring the fact that **how** you use that IGBT (what circuit, driver) has a significant impact on how fast this IGBT can switch. I can make a circuit that makes the on/off switching so slow that the highest frequency is 1 Hz (one Hertz). I can probably (no guarantees) switch at 1 MHz if I would use the right circuit.

Comment: Normally you choose the switching frequency first, and select a device that matches your requirements at that frequency. For example, having suggested 250kHz, take the datasheet for that part and calculate its efficiency at that frequency. Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes, it could switch a non-inductive resistor at 3MHz, but I suspect you have more demanding design specs than this,

Comment: Ouh so the limiting factor is the load type,swicthing loses and the swicthing  capabability of the driver to drive the igbt